# How does google-api-js-client (gapi) restore sign in state across sessions and refreshes

Tags: google-oauth, google-api-js-client

It's very nice that the gapi api is able to keep a user signed in but I would like to understand how it does it.

In the [developer docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#gapiauth2initparams) it states that

> Then, if the user has already signed in, the GoogleAuth object restores the user's sign-in state from the previous session.

The only way I know of doing this is by using a refresh token which is insecure if stored on the client.

How does the gapi-api acheive this?

I would refer to the sources, but I [don't think](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/blob/master/javascripts/main.js) they are open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it calls the OAuth endpoint with `prompt=none` in a hidden iframe.
You're right that the libs are closed source, which is great reason to not use them. It's not difficult to write your own OAuth implementation.

Comment: I see. I confused token expiry with session expiry. I now see that the default session length for Google services is 14 days. I guess you can use prompt=none without the user having to re authenticate in that time.